# How will I list the packages that are installed in my Ubuntu 18.04, when apt list --installed is not showing anything?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management

[image: Apt list --installed]

No matter how many times I tried the command `apt list --installed` it will only show "Listing... Done". I even tried saving it as a text but still it didn't give me anything.

[image: dpkg --list : grep '^i']

Trying this command still showed nothing.....

Comment: Did you try `apt update` and `apt upgrade` ?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) Copy the text here and use code formatting. https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Additionally, please add the output of `apt-config dump` and `stat /var/lib/dpkg/status` (as text, not screenshots)

Comment: @deimos, I am not the OP, but have exactly the same issue as the OP. > 
Did you try `apt update` and `apt upgrade`? - Yes, I ran both those commands. Still getting nothing but `Listing... Done` - in my case when I run `apt list d*`. I know for certain that I have packages installed whose name start on `d`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `dpkg`. This will only show installed packages:

```
dpkg --list | grep '^i'
```

Comment: it showed nothing.

Comment: _JanelleAllidem_, when responding, please put your findings, not in Add Comment, but instead in the Question (i.e., I tried _dpkg --list | grep '^i'_ and here's the result...) by clicking [edit] and putting what you tried and what the result was in your question. Why? Comments pile up and old comments get pushed off screen. Please try _dpkg -l | grep '^ii'_ and let us know the result. PS: Instead of pasting a screenshot in, please copy the text and paste the text into your question instead.